# Getting followers information using Tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy, rate-limiting

I have all the followers IDs in a list that I got using the following code. Now I want to get all those IDs' information (`followers_count`, `friends_count`, `verified`, etc.) What changes do I need in order to get 18000 results per 15 minutes. I got 75000 IDs using the following code in 15 minutes.

```
counter = 0
reset_counter = 0
loop_counter = True
backoff_timer = 2 # counter for timer

while loop_counter:
    try:
        for friend in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids, id='adl440', count=5000).items():
            time.sleep(0.01)
            reset_counter += 1 # reser 1
            # this is reducing the waiting time

            counter += 1 #count 1
            # max collection 5*15K =75K in 15 mins
            # insert the information into the table
            #uid_json = {'uid': friend}
            #collection.insert_one(uid_json)
            # # saving the txt file
            
            print(str(friend))
            csvWriter.writerow(str(friend))
            count +=1
            print(count)

        break

    except tweepy.TweepError as err:
        print(err.reason)
        time.sleep(60 * backoff_timer)
        sleep_time = 60 * backoff_timer
        print('Error Generated by Tweepy API sleep {0} seconds.'.format(round(sleep_time,2)))
        backoff_timer += 1
        continue
```

I tried getting the data using API lookup method but couldn't succeed. Every time I try I get very little results in the output and suddenly I hit the the rate limit.

Comment: tweepy has got some limit I guess. You need to use some third party application or try to automate the process using selenium.(web scrapping without using any official API)

Comment: Tweepy itself is not rate limtied. The Twitter API endpoints that Tweepy uses has rate limits. Also, scraping Twitter without using the official API violates [Twitter's Terms of Service](https://twitter.com/en/tos).

Answer (score 0):

The [GET users/lookup](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-users-lookup) Twitter API endpoint that [`API.lookup_users`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#tweepy.API.lookup_users) uses returns 100 users per request. The rate limit for the endpoint is 900 requests / 15 min. with user auth and 300 requests / 15 min. with app auth. This means that you should be able to retrieve 30,000 or 90,000 users per 15-min. window, depending on if you're using app auth or user auth.

Comment: How should I modify this code to get this much of data?

Comment: By calling `API.lookup_users` with 100 IDs at a time